# Understanding Alloy cardinality

Tags: alloy

I haven't been able to understand Alloy cardinality.  I reduced my code down to this trivial example which Alloy can't find an instance for:

```
sig A {}
sig B { s: set A}

fact x { one n: Int  | all b: B | #(b.s) = n }
run {} for 10
```

Namely, that the cardinality of B.s must be the same for all members of B.  Why can't Alloy find an example of that?

Answer (score 2):

If you change your `run` command to `run {} for 10 but 5 int` you should start seeing instances.

This isn't really a satisfactory answer (I hope one of the members of the Alloy team can do better), but it looks as if the immediate problem is that while Int is built-in, it is not always instantiated.  When there are no instances of Int, the fact cannot be satisfied.  (Comment the fact out, generate an instance, and then ask the Evaluator to evaluate the expression `Int`.  When I did that, the evaluator returned {}.)

I would gladly explain this better, but I have not succeeded in finding or discovering the rules which determine when Int atoms are generated and when they are not.

Answer (score 1):

In Options you can set message verbosity to High. There, when you run a command you will see that the bitwidth (which determines the max Int for Alloy) is 0. This used to be 4 by default, I'm not sure what is going on.

As suggested by another answer, setting Int to some value increases bitwidth, and therefore increases maximum Int allowed by Alloy.

Working with Int is really discouraged in Alloy. Here is a way to write the same statement, avoiding Int:

```
sig A {}
sig B { s: set A}

fact x { all b,b2: B | #(b.s) = #(b2.s) }
run { some B.s and #B>1} for 10
```

I added something to the run statement just to see some interesting instances